# GNU Parallel host sticky jobs

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, gnu

I am writing a parallel build farm to build C++ cross-platform applications against various platforms / environments. Every time new code is pushed to a git repo, I build and test the latest code against all the platforms.

I've setup parallel to correctly distribute the jobs among several hosts using the --sshlogin option.
I transfer files, collect output and results. It's all working more than fine and I love the tool.

The build time being sometimes quite long for some platforms, I would like the build to be as incremental as possible.

My only issue is that the build is only incremental if the scheduler sends the jobs to the same machine and reuse the artefacts of the previous build on this specific host.

Say I have 3 hosts, I have 1 chance in 3 for the build to be incremental. If a hosts hasn't built this platform in a while, it might take a long time.

Is it possible to gain control over the host a specific input source will run on and only fallback to the other hosts if the host is busy?

Ideally, I would love to see a tag system where I tag input source with a name and tag several hosts with a name, creating pools of jobs and pools of machines specialized into that type of build.

But a very simple implementation where the input sources are distributed in the same order as the order the sshlogins are defined could be a simple & quick fix in my situation.

I tried to find the source code to implement it myself but I only see doc generation when I browse the code on Savannah.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying to discuss this idea on the mailing list as you suggested but never had any respone in more than 10 days... I guess you must be busy with other things at the moment. So I went along and forked the source code to make the necessary changes and make my solution work.
I pushed it there a week ago:

http://michakfromparis.github.io/gnu-parallel-sticky/

the source code is available on github here:

https://github.com/michaKFromParis/gnu-parallel-sticky

Wasn't exactly easy without any guidance as the source code has a lot of history so I tried to keep the changes surgical to ease merge of your future releases.
I've been using it in production for more than a week now and it works perfectly in my configuration.
It is also compatible with older formats, should be a drop-in replacement for usual parallel uses with extra features on the side.
Would love to get feedback from other users though as it might not be completely dry.
Thanks for sharing the original source code.

Best Regards,

M

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no support for prioritizing a given argument to a given sshlogin. The source code is at https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=parallel

Feel free to join the mailing list and discuss the idea: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

The only priority in the code is when a job has failed on an sshlogin, then GNU Parallel prefers to retry that job on another sshlogin. Maybe that could be extended?

If a job is marked as having failed -1 time for a given sshlogin, then GNU Parallel ought to prefer to run the job on that sshlogin.